# Is it possible to use other class variable in other class at @Override Java

Tags: java

I was wondering is there a way to use other class variable in @Override?
Here is my first class. I've tried to use setters & getters, but still receiving an error:

```
public class Darbuotojas {
String dVardas;
String dPavarde;
int dAmzius;
int dPatirtis;

Programuotojas programuotojas = new Programuotojas();
String check = programuotojas.getDarboKalba();

Darbuotojas() { }
public Darbuotojas(String dVardas, String dPavarde, int dAmzius, int dPatirtis) {
    this.dVardas = dVardas;
    this.dPavarde = dPavarde;
    this.dAmzius = dAmzius;
    this.dPatirtis = dPatirtis;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return dVardas + " " + dPavarde + " " + dAmzius + " " + dPatirtis + " " + check;
}}
```

And here is my another class:

```
public class Programuotojas extends Darbuotojas {
Programuotojas(){}

public String getDarboKalba() {
    return darboKalba;
}

public void setDarboKalba(String darboKalba) {
    this.darboKalba = darboKalba;
}

public String darboKalba;
public Programuotojas(String dVardas, String dPavarde, int dAmzius, int dPatirtis, String darboKalba) {
    super(dVardas, dPavarde, dAmzius, dPatirtis);
    this.darboKalba = darboKalba;
}
```

As I see I formulated bad and not understandable question for you guys. I will try to explain. I have father class Darbuotojas with 4 parameters, in subclass Programuotojas I add one more parameter - darboKalba. So what I want from Override to return these 4 paremeters from Darbuotojas + one from Programuotojas.

```
// Darbuotoju valdymas prasideda //
public void darbuotojuVald() {
    System.out.println("---- Darbuotoju valdymas ----");
    System.out.println("[1] Prideti nauja darbuotoja");
    System.out.println("[2] Pasalinti darbuotoja");
    System.out.println("[3] Atnaujinti darbuotoja");
    System.out.println("[4] Pamatyti darbuotoju sarasa");
    System.out.println("[5] Gauti informacija apie pasirinkta darbuotoja");
    Scanner SI = new Scanner(System.in);
    int vartotojoIvestis = Integer.parseInt(SI.nextLine());
    if (vartotojoIvestis == 1) {
        System.out.println("---- Prideti nauja darbuotoja ----");
        System.out.println("[1] Programuotoja");
        System.out.println("[2] kita");
        int vartotojoIvestis2 = Integer.parseInt(SI.nextLine());
        if (vartotojoIvestis2 == 1) {
            pridetiDarbuotojaProgramuotoja();
        } else {
            System.out.println("In progress....");
        }
    } else if (vartotojoIvestis == 4) {
        bendrasDarbuotojuSarasas();
    }
}

// Programuotojo pridejimas prasideda //
private void pridetiDarbuotojaProgramuotoja() {
    System.out.println("---- Pridedamas naujas programuotojas ----");
    System.out.println("Iveskite:");
    System.out.println("Varda, pavarde, amziu, patirti, programavimo kalba");
    Scanner SI = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] iveda = SI.nextLine().split(" ");
    programuotojas.add(new Programuotojas(iveda[0], iveda[1], Integer.parseInt(iveda[2]), Integer.parseInt(iveda[3]), iveda[4]));
    System.out.println("---- Sekmingai pridetas naujas darbuotojas ----");
    System.out.println("Vardas: " + iveda[0]
            + ",pavarde: " + iveda[1]
            + ",amzius: " + iveda[2]
            + ",patirtis: " + iveda[3]
            + ",programavimo kalba: " + iveda[4]);
    darbuotojuSarasas.clear();
    darbuotojuSarasas.addAll(programuotojas);
    darbuotojuVald();
}

private void bendrasDarbuotojuSarasas() {
    System.out.println("---- Visas darbuotoju sarasas ----");
    for(int i = 0; i < darbuotojuSarasas.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("ID " + i + " " + darbuotojuSarasas.get(i));
    }
    darbuotojuVald();
}
```

Comment: ehm, what does not work? what is the question now? and why the `regex` tag?

Comment: If you mean the `toString()` method in the super class, then no, it can't magically access variables in a subclass.  You could use reflection, but that's a little ugly.

Comment: Sorry for bad tag. @markspace is there any other way to solve this problem without reflection?

Comment: Did not understand your question. Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish and how these classes are being used in your program.

Comment: Can't paste full code, but in top of the the last code there are:package com.Moda;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DarbuotojuValdymas {

    private ArrayList<Programuotojas> programuotojas = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Darbuotojas> darbuotojuSarasas = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Solved my problem..

Answer (score 0):

Reflection can be tricky, and I can't guarantee it'll work for all circumstances.  This worked well enough for me.

```
package quicktest;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Brenden
 */
public class FieldDumpTest {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      System.out.println( new FieldDump3() );
   }

   public final String topTestString = "This is a test.";
   protected int topInt = 11;
   float topFloat = 123.456f;
   private short topShort = Short.MAX_VALUE;

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
      Class<?> type = this.getClass();
      do {
         str.append( type.getName() );
         str.append( " {" );
         Field[] fields = type.getDeclaredFields();
         for( int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++ ) {
            Field field = fields[i];
            str.append( field.getName() );
            str.append( ":" );
            try {
               str.append( field.get( this ) );
            } catch( IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException ex ) {
               str.append( "<NO ACCESS>" );
            }
            str.append( ", " );
         }
         str.append(  "}  " );
         type = type.getSuperclass();
      } while( type != null );
      return str.toString();
   }

}

class FieldDump2 extends FieldDumpTest {
   private String test  = "testtest";
}

class FieldDump3 extends FieldDump2 {
   int ten = 10;
   protected double fortytwo = 42.0;
}
```

Output:

```
run:
quicktest.FieldDump3 {ten:10, fortytwo:42.0, }  quicktest.FieldDump2 {test:<NO ACCESS>, }  quicktest.FieldDumpTest {topTestString:This is a test., topInt:11, topFloat:123.456, topShort:32767, }  java.lang.Object {}  
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```